# Пинговать пока не выполнится условие

Tags: java

Как пинговать локалхост до наступления условия?
Так пока не работает.

```
package ping;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress; 
import java.io.File;
public class ping {
public void checkPing() throws IOException { 
    Process ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 10 localhost"); 
    ping.waitFor();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try {
```

if () checkPing();
}

```
catch (Exception e) {
    //System.out.println(e);
        }
```

}
}

Comment: можно while-do или что-то типа того, или рекурсию с методом

Comment: у меня трудность в том чтобы повторно запустить пинг. Нужно создавать новый процесс ping2 например? Как это сделать неизвестное число раз?

Comment: число раз я думаю смысла нету пробрасывать, просто запускать пока не выполнится условие, можно создать новый пинг в теле условия или использовать ранее инициализированный

Comment: Пример можете написать, как запустить второй раз, не вводя новую переменную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повторно послать ping можно так

```
  Process ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 2 localhost");
            ping.waitFor();
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 5 localhost");
                ping.waitFor();
             System.out.println(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот например использование метода проверки пинга:

```
public void checkPing(){
Process ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 10 localhost"); 
ping.waitFor();

if(condition){

}else{
checkPing();
}

}
```

либо через while/do-while:

```
do {
  // code block to be executed
}
while (condition);
```

Вот [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_while_loop.asp) можно чекнуть. Вот [тут](https://www.javatpoint.com/recursion-in-java#:%7E:text=Recursion%20in%20java%20is%20a,compact%20but%20complex%20to%20understand.) про рекурсию можно прочитать. По поводу ввода новой переменной - сделайте глобальную переменную в классе, присвойте ей значение и запускайте пинг. Не факт что прям идеальное решение, но я так понимаю :)

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос как 2 раза подряд напсать Process ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 10 localhost");

Comment: а зачем два раза подряд? не очень понял если честно))

Comment: я не дописал) Проверил . static void checkPing(){
  Process ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 10 localhost"); 
  ping.waitFor();

 } описать функцию, а потом вызвать в коде checkPing(); не работает

Comment: а зачем вы сделали метод статичным? у вас есть какое-то требование?)

Comment: public тоже не работал)

Comment: вы это в пределах одного класса пытаетесь реализовать? просто я пробовал этот код у себя и вызывать метод из него же получилось нормально вроде)

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method checkPing() from the type ping ошибка. В пределах одного класса

Comment: а можете показать свой класс где вы это пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: package ping;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress; 
import java.io.File;
public class ping {
 public void checkPing() throws IOException { 
  Process ping = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 10 localhost"); 
  ping.waitFor();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   try {
  checkPing();
          }
          
    catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println(e);
            }
}
}

Comment: приложите код в ваш вопрос, а то мешанину такую сложно читать :)